# Dynamic creation of Spring Batch jobs without XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

is it possible to setup Spring Batch without XML for jobs?

Currently, there are a lot of those job beans defined in XML:

```
<bean id="sampleJob" class="com.test.job.TestJob">
    <property name="idBase" value="SampleId" />
    <property name="targetTableName" value="SAMPLE_TABLE" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value><![CDATA[
        SELECT 42 FROM 1337
        ]]></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring Batch runs every night in our app. I want to make it possible to edit the job's properties. The idea is to get the injected properties from a database instead of hardcoding them in XML.

Please tell me if you've got a better idea how to solve the problem. Currently, I want to implement a kind of factory which provides a methode like that:

```
public TestJob createJob(String name) {
    String sql = db.getSqlFor(name);
    String table = db.getTableFor(name);
    ...
    return new TestJob(sql, table, ...);
}
```

Does Spring Batch offer these possibilites? I googled a lot but didn't find a satisfying solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it does. Have you looked at http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/#quick-start ?

Comment: Yes I did. However, it's not clear to me how to handle the dynamics in that use case. The job information will be read successively from the database and I want to create dynamic Jobs at runtime where it isn't exactly clear how many jobs there will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. just use the different builders provided by SpringBatch in order to create your job dynamically.

The steps and all reader and writer which they use don't have to be spring beans (of course, there will be no autowiring in this case, which forces you to do this yourself).

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleJobConfiguration {
    private static final String JOB_NAME = "SimpleTestJob";

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = this.jobs.get(createJobName(JOB_NAME)).start(firstStep());

        for ... {
            jobBuilder.next(createAStep( ... params ...));
        }

        return standardJob.build();
    }

    public Step createAStep(String name, ... needed parameters ...) throws Exception {
        StepBuilder stepBuilder = this.steps.get(name);

        build your step

        return standardStep1.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you only create one job with different steps? Currently, we define a bunch of jobs which execute one step.

Comment: yes. I would implement one job and use as splitflow in which every table has its own step. As far as I understood, these steps will be completely indepedent, so , if you provide a AsyncTaskExecutor to the splitflow, they will even run in parallel. Note: you can also create a job for every table and add it as a "JobStep" to the splitflow. This would result in a major job that executes several "sub jobs".